# Se puede cambiar la propiedad 'username' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''), y obtener el usuario desde la base de datos? en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel 6 y quiero que el administrador del sistema pueda cambiar los valores de sus pagos en paypal, lo que trato de hacer es que se obtengan los datos de paypal desde la base de datos.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré mi respuesta.

Cree un provider, a el mismo le agregue esto:

```
        App::singleton('Paypal_username', function(){
         $user=DB::table('settings')->where('key_name','slogan')- 
           >pluck('value');
        $p_user='';
        foreach ($user as $us){ 
            $p_user=$us;
        }
        config(['app.paypal_username' => $p_user]);
        return $p_user;
    })
```

y solo lo llamo así: config('app.paypal_username'), en mi archivo de configuración